# Get the number of rows inserted in the database per hour

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, count, date-arithmetic

I know there are similar questions already, but I can't find a clear and simple answer.

I have this query :

```
"SELECT dbo.tbTransaction.dateHeure, dbo.tbTransaction.Etat, dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste
        FROM dbo.tbTransaction 
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbPoste ON dbo.tbTransaction.ID_poste = dbo.tbPoste.ID_POSTE
        WHERE dbo.tbPoste.id_site LIKE 47 
        AND dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste LIKE '0909_CLIENT'
        AND dateHeure >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
        ORDER BY dateHeure DESC";
```

It enables me to fetch all the database insertions of the d`ay(>= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0))` on a particular post (0909_CLIENT), sorted by the most recent time of insertion(`ORDER BY dateHeure DESC`).

I would like to be able to retrieve the number of inserts per hour, the goal is to be able to generate live graphics hour by hour.

I manage to get the total number of insertions during the day with :

```
$params = array();
    $options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result ). PHP_EOL;
    echo '<br>';
     if ($row_count === false)
     echo "Error in retrieveing row count;
    else {
      echo $row_count;
     }
```

I can see the lines entered in the database at a particular time with :

```
$five = "05:";
$six = "06:";
$seven = "07:";


if ($result === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        $heureformate = $row["dateHeure"]->format('H:i');
        
        if (strpos($heureformate, $five) !== false) {
            echo $heureformate;
            echo '<br>';
            //count(array($heureformate));
        } elseif (strpos($heureformate, $six) !== false) {
            echo $heureformate;
            echo '<br>';
        } elseif (strpos($heureformate, $seven) !== false) {
            echo $heureformate;
            echo '<br>';
        } 
    } 
}
```

But as I told you, I don't manage to get the number of lines entered per hour and it's this number that interests me to create  graphics.

If you have any ideas on how to get this number in `SQL` or `PHP`, please help me.

Comment: Try adding `group by hour(your_datetime_column)` to your query.

Comment: I tried but I have "Hour is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: oh sorry I thought this was mysql.

Comment: Don't worry, thx for the suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want aggregation?

```
select  datepart(hour, t.dateheure), count(*) as cnt
from dbo.tbtransaction t
inner join dbo.tbposte p on t.id_poste = p.id_poste
where p.id_site = 47 and p.nomposte = '0909_client' and t.dateheure >= cast(gedate() as date)
group by datepart(hour, dateheure)
```

This filters the dataset for rows whose `dateheure` belongs to the current day, and counts how many records there is in each hour.

Note that I simplified the date filtering logic, and turned the `like` conditions to equalities (since no wildcards are involved, both are equivalent).

Comment: Hello sir, do you know if it's possible to add additional restrictions in this query?
For instance, specify time slots or restrict to the last ten hours ?
I'm eager to learn, don't hesitate to share with me some tutorials or websites on this subject (apart from the microsoft documentation) if you have this.